# How can I update the radio-firmware for my Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, radio-firmware

The radio on my Galaxy Note 2 has been acting up and I've read that this can be fixed by updating the baseband/radio-firmware.

Where can I find the firmware for my device? My device's baseband is currently shown as `XXALIE`. Is that the only firmware I can install or can I choose any of the `XX` ones.

Comment: Radio firmware is usually provided by the manufacturer directly. But you might want to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for additional sources; it's not a rare case that a source for custom ROMs points to recommended radio-firmware to be used along.

Comment: Try searching in the XDA forums. You would have better chances there.

Comment: XDA is the place to try. You'll need the USB drivers and ODIN to flash it, and to ensure NO Kies services are running. Ensure the modem is for the EXACT model of Note 2 you are using. Also Modems are region specific so the 'latest' one may not work on your network. Make sure you have a few downloaded, including your current one as backup before flashing a new one. (I recently made a complete mess of it myself so just a friendly warning!)